# Why I receive warning in objectForKey method?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, type-conversion

I need to execute method in

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

I have an `NSDictionary` from which I want to get ID (long) and send it to my method:

```
    long sect = (long)section;
    [objectp.methodA countRowsInSection:[tableSections objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", sect]]]
```

I receive warning:

```
Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'id' to parameter of type 'long'
```

Why?

I try to convert `NSInteger` to long and then to `NSString`, but warning is still there.

**REMARK:** `countRowsInSection` is `long`.

I store data in `NSDictionary` as `NSString`:

```
[tableSections setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", newCategoryID]
   forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", counter]];
```

Comment: Of what type is the `sect ` variable used in the format?

Comment: Sorry @rckoenes, it is `long` - `long sect = (long)section;`

Comment: Try and spilt up the method, this might give you a better view of where the error is. Because now I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: Carefully look at the little arrow that the compiler uses to show you where the error is. It is not warning you about sect. It is warning you about the object that you pass to countRowsInSection:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `countRowsInSection:` seems to expect its argument to be a `long`. But you're sending it an object (probably an `NSNumber`). If that is the case, the following will work:

```
[objectp.methodA countRowsInSection:[[tableSections objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", sect] longValue]]];
```

Comment: I also convert `id` to `long`

Answer (score 0):

> I have an NSDictionary from which I want to get ID (long) and send it to my method:

No, you do not want to get an ID with type `long` from a dictionary, because `long` is a C type and cannot be stored in a dictionary. Likely it is an instance of `NSString` or `NSNumber`. Then you take this as a parameter for `-countRowsInSection:`, which likely expects an `NSInteger` or `long`, therefore a C type.

Comment: Yes, @Amin Negm-Awad, I store it as `NSString`: `[tableSections setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", newCategoryID]
                                 forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", counter]];`

Comment: Well, this is not the best idea. You should use an instance of `NSNumber`. However, you can retrieve the `long` value with `-intValue`, if your value does not exceed `INT_MAX`. `NSNumber` is the better choice by far, at least because you can use `@(newCategoryID)` and `-longValue` to retrieve it.